# Change menu and window theme in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I'm using the Darcula theme in Intelli IDEAJ because it is easier on the eyes, but it seems to only affect the editor.

It really doesn't do much for me, since everything else (menus, etc.) are unaffected and contrast harshly.

Is there a way for me to change these as well?

[image: Intellij IDEA screenshot]

I believe I saw someone do this once, but I may have been mistaken and looking at another IDE.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quickest way: `View menu` -> `Quick Switch Scheme` -> `5. Switch Look and Feel` -> `Darcula`

Comment: Also, ctrl-Backquote is the default keybinding for this.

Comment: This is the shortcut, but it doesn't answer the question, but @Dan does below. This is only step 1/2; you still need to change the preference.

Comment: Yeah - this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

You need to also change Appearance theme in Preferences.

(It's confusing that changing the theme doesn't actually change the theme in the whole IDE.)

Comment: Annoying is the fact that e.g. ER Diagram uses Theme from Preferences -> Appearance and normal code editor Scheme from Editor -> Color & Fonts.