# Intellij switching themes

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been using the darcula theme for a while and wanted to move back to default.

When I switch only the editor goes back to default even after I restart.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: For test, I changed theme and then I restarted my pc, but it works fine (both editor and everything)

Comment: Is a machine reboot really necessary... I'll give it a go.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073301/change-menu-and-window-theme-in-intellij

Comment: Yes could be - even though that's the other way round.  The solution there didn't work for me.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you mad? :D Only joking -- I've just tried it here, and restarting the IDE was all that was necessary to make this work ok. Are you really shutting down the IDE before restarting it? If you're on a mac, this can be somewhat confusing to anyone who expects thing to behave in some sort of rational manor.

Comment: I found the answer and put it into the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1.** You choose menu **File \ Settings...** or press **Ctrl + Alt + S**.
[image]
**Step 2**. In Settings windows, choose IDE Settings group, choose **Appearance**, in **Theme** dropdown menu, choose **Alloy.IDEA Theme** (It is the default theme). Press **Apply** then press **OK**.
[image]
**Step 3.** Restart IntelliJ IDEA 13
[image]

**This is the default interface, it was back to normal:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to also change Appearance theme in Preferences.

(It's confusing that changing the theme in the quick theme change doesn't actually change the theme in the whole IDE.)